# Google Colab is crashing due to excessive usage of RAM

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory

I am building a CNN model with a 230 MB size image dataset and Google Colab is crashing even with mini-batches of 16 and 8. There are overall 40k images.
Please suggest a remedy for the same or suggest another free platform with better memory capacity.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GR75c.png)

Warning message before crashing: "tensorflow/core/framework/cpu_allocator_impl.cc:82] Allocation of 834978816 exceeds 10% of free system memory."

Comment: without your code it isn't possible to give you advices

Comment: Size of CNN (very unlikely), infinite loop storing images or data, self replicating code etc might be some cases.

Comment: There aren't any infinite or self-replicating codes. What I should do then, any suggestions?

Comment: @juuso  I have attached a screenshot of the codes I am using... Please check if you could suggest something.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I figured it out by significantly reducing the size of input images and decreasing the number of parameters by using fewer Convolutional layers. RAM over usage problem is sorted for now, though it will impact on overall model performance.